# Modulo Euler's Totient Function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Prove or disprove: $2^a \equiv 2^b \pmod{m} \text{ iff } a \equiv b \pmod{\phi{(m)}}$.

Through some testing, I found that this is true. How can I prove this?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, please read [Multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order).

Comment: @JohnOmielan I see now, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your specific question, note that $2^0 \equiv 2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, but $\varphi(7) = 6$.

Answer (score -1):

It is valid for $m$ odd ($gcd(m,2)=1$) due to Euler's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).
If $ a \equiv b \mod m$
$$ \Rightarrow a-b=k\phi(m)$$
$$ \Rightarrow 2^{a-b}=2^{k\phi(m)}=\left(2^{\phi(m)}\right)^k\equiv 1^k \equiv 1\mod m, \gcd(2,m)=1$$.
It is not valid for $m$ even, for example $m=6, \phi(6)=2, a=0, b=2$.